# How to make a copy of an object containing a list of shared pointers?

Tags: c++, copy, shared-ptr

I would like to make a copy of an object from the following class:

```
class EventPacket
{

public:
    std::list<std::shared_ptr <Event> >::iterator it;
    std::list<std::shared_ptr <Event> > EventList;
    EventPacket();
    ~EventPacket();

    EventPacket* clone();

    void add(std::shared_ptr<Event> event);
    std::shared_ptr<Event> pop();

    std::list<std::shared_ptr <Event> >::iterator begin(void);
    std::list<std::shared_ptr <Event> >::iterator end(void);
};
```

Therefore I've implemented the following function:

```
EventPacket* EventPacket::clone() {
EventPacket *copy = new EventPacket();
*copy = *this;
return copy;
```

}

It compiles and it seems to run but I'm not sure whether the shared pointers were copied properly such that they remain shared pointers in the copied object. Say, if I copy an object `Eventpacket* ep` (assuming its `Eventlist` contains a number of `Event` objects) and delete the copy afterwards

```
EventPacket *copy = ep->clone();
delete copy;
```

will the list of events be automatically released as one would expect it from a list of shared pointers?

Comment: Why mess around with `new`? What's wrong with regular copy semantics, `EventPacket copy = ep;`?

Comment: Use copying constructor instead: `EventPacked::EventPacked(const EventPacked&)=default`, then you can simply do `EventPacked _new(_old);`

Comment: For God's sake use typedef

Comment: i have a few other member functions that i've removed here for the sake of visibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > but I'm not sure whether the shared pointers were copied properly such that they remain shared pointers in the copied object

They were.

Copying a `shared_ptr` increases it reference count by one, so in your example deleting `copy` will not release the events yet, but once `ep` also gets deleted they will.

Keep in mind that a cloned `EventPacket` shares the `Event` objects with the original, this may or may not be desired.

Comment: Oops... this is not desired. I don't want that the cloned EventPacket shares the Event. I want that it also makes copies of all Events... is that possible?

Comment: In this case, first of all you may consider unique_ptr instead of shared_ptr for holding the events. At least if EventPacket is the only one who holds a strong (owning, lifetime extending) ref to it. Second, you will have to manually create copies of all Event objects as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should copy the class directly, i.e.

```
EventPacket eventPacket;
// Do stuff 
EventPacket copy = eventPacket;
```

as your class can be copied without any further operation. Indeed, the compiler generates a copy constructor (aptly called *implicit*) when you don't specify one, if possible (i.e. if your class can be trivially copied, which is the case here as every private member defines itself a copy constructor).

Then, the shared pointers will be copied correctly, the class is basically meant for handling this case. A shared pointer can be passed around and copied as needed, while pointing to the same memory, and is guaranteed to be deleted exactly when there's no more reference to it from any living object/function.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the list will copy the shared pointers, sharing ownership of the `Event` objects. They will be deleted when removed from *both* lists.

The implicit copy constructor and assignment operator will do this. In your code, that happens via assignment in `*copy = *this`. In more sensible code,

```
EventPacket copy = ep;
```

the copy constructor copies all the shared pointers.